# Coordinates extraction of SVG file objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, svg

I have a SVG of a floorplan from which I am trying to extract the coordinates of all the text (i.e. roomnumbers) and objects (i.e. tables) for a rails app I am making. I tried looking for gems and such that might help but everything seemed to be very old/broken, so how would I go about processing a SVG file so that I could, say, store all the x-y coordinates of its components in a ruby hash?

Comment: Have you looked at RMagick? https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick

Comment: I did, but all I saw was functions to draw svg iamges, not read them for the data they may contain

Comment: http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html

Comment: So for all the 'path' elements that show up as a result of Nokogiri's output, are the  path's the locations of each of those objects? I am still confused as to how that'd give me location, I don't see any bounding box data in the output.

Comment: Did some tinkering, and managed to get the boundsBox with rmagick and nokogiri, so thanks guys!

Comment: @AnirudhJagdish SVG is vector fileformat encoded as XML so if you know how the stuff you're looking for is encoded then you can directly read it from the XML ... for example parsing path elements is easy ... Text tags are also easily detectable (unless polygons are used instead of text). So try to write own parser for only features you want. Do not forget to apply all transform matrices along the way. Without any example SVG is hard to advice any more then that.

Comment: NokoGiri makes life quiet easy for parsing out the tags I need, so I didn't need to write my own parser. Here is a sample of what I am getting in my xml file:

Comment: <g id="TEXT_72_">
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 41.1798 128.2293)" style="fill:#FF00FF; font-family:'MyriadPro-Regular'; font-size:1.7695px;">834.K3</text>
        </g>